# Query to update one row on the basis of another

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem with a query. I tried to find the answer but couldn't find it.

I have 2 rows for some employees in my table. I want to keep the recent ones and delete the old one's.. but before that I want to update some null columns of my new rows from data from old rows of same employee. E.g.

[image]

I want to update IDs 1 and 3 so that only the null columns are updated and non-null columns are not updated, so that the data becomes

The output should be like:

[image]

I can delete the duplicates in the end because IDs of the old data are in a known sequence.

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Add a unique constraint for employee_no. (And this wont happen again...)

Comment: this happened because i am integrating data from some other database to my database.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
UPDATE EMP1
SET
    Name = CASE
               WHEN EMP2.Name IS NULL THEN EMP2.Name
           END
FROM
    Employee AS EMP1
    INNER JOIN Employee AS EMP2 ON EMP1.Employee_no = EMP2.Employee_no AND EMP1.ID <> EMP2.ID
```

Comment: What type of database do you have? MSSQL, Oracle, MySQL? Some semantics might differ in the update clause (this solution is specific to MSSQL)

Answer (score 0):

You can update it as:

```
UPDATE employee e
set dob = (
  select db from (
    select dob 
            over (partition by dob order by employeeno) db
     from employee
  ) ee
  where ee.employeeno = e.employeeno
)
```